# Проверить значение в словаре на .jpg или .png python

Tags: python

Есть словарь.. который состоит из вложенных словарей который указан ниже. Нужно в цикле пройтись по ним  и проверить чтобы 'attachments': не равнялся None а также чтобы в нем было .jpg или .png а если будет что-то другое написать.. Неправильный формат изображения..

```
{'status': 'success', 'result': [{'id': 2431449991, 'answered': True, 'client_replica': True, 'message_id': None, 'message_from_outside': 0, 'created_at': 1666118252, 'text': '', 'attachments': ['https://files.salebot.pro/uploads/message_files/bc21fa26-0f19-4ef9-a2b7-6f08632a0115.jpg'], 'delivered': True, 'error_message': 'true'}.......

for i in row['result']:
   if i['attachments'] !=None:
```

не знаю как дальше

Answer (score 1):

Если у вас в **attachments** будет всегда одна строка, то будет работать. Если там несколько, надо будет менять **[0]** перед **split**. Если данных много, чтобы долго не выполнялось, необходимо немного улучшить данный код.

```
row = {'status': 'success', 'result': [
    {'id': 2431449991, 'answered': True, 'client_replica': True, 'message_id': None, 'message_from_outside': 0,
     'created_at': 1666118252, 'text': '',
     'attachments': ['https://files.salebot.pro/uploads/message_files/bc21fa26-0f19-4ef9-a2b7-6f08632a0115.jpg'],
     'delivered': True, 'error_message': 'true'}]}

for i in row['result']:
    if i['attachments'] != None:
        split_attachments = i['attachments'][0].split('.')
        img_format = split_attachments[len(split_attachments) - 1]
        if (img_format == "jpg" or img_format == "png"):
            print("Формат правильный")
        else:
            print("Не правильный формат")
```

Comment: Хорошо бы ```!= None``` поправить на ```is not None```, чтобы соответствовало PEP8